# Skip re-building a heavy loading widget when it is not currently viewed

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter screen widget A containing 10000 elements. It takes time to load this widget every time when flutter build it.

At the same time, I do Navigator.push in this widget to open a new screen B.

Every time when I push a new screen C in screen B, or pop the screen C, flutter re-build the widget A. It takes time to build the screen widget A while that screen is currently not being viewed. It is just in the background.

I would like to skip building the screen widget A if it is not veiwed.
May I know is it possible to do so?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/MaterialPageRoute/maintainState.html `false`,
or just store the widget in a variable and return the same instance every time `build()` is called..

Comment: It is great to store the widget in a variable and return the same instance every time build() is called. After doing this, the setState is not simple anymore. However, I should go with this solution for better performance. Thanks for your help!